# Consumir Api rest con Visual Basic.net

Tags: vb.net, .net, api, rest, tokens

de ante mano gracias por cualquier ayuda, quisiera consumir un api rest que tiene autenticacion OAuth2.0 es decir por token.

Me gustaría para comenzar es poder realizar la petición post a la url enviandole las credenciales pero no tengo ni idea de como hacerlo y he buscado ejemplos en la web y he de admito que son muy ambiguos.

Si alguien tiene algún ejemplo o la estructura de como hacerlo estaría muy agradecido

Comment: Mira [ask] <- ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] <- ACA para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Las preguntas que piden recomendaciones o ejemplos no son bien vistas. Tenes que buscar por vos mismo, y cuando tengas un problema particular venir a preguntar sobre el mismo aca.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la librería RestSharp, para instalarla usa el siguiente comando en consola administración de paquetes

Install-Package RestSharp -Version 106.3.1

```
       using RestSharp;
       using RestSharp.Authenticators;
       using System.Collections;
       using System.Dynamic;
```

//Con este metodo obtienes el token

```
        public string getToken(String sURL, String sUserName, String sPassword)
         {  String access_token = "";
             string clientId = "client";
             string clientSecret = "secret";
             string credentials = String.Format("{0}:{1}", clientId, clientSecret);
             RestClient restClient = new RestClient(sURL);
             RestRequest restRequest = new RestRequest("/oauth/token");
             restRequest.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
             restRequest.Method = Method.POST;
             restRequest.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(credentials)));
             restRequest.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
             restRequest.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
             restRequest.AddParameter("grant_type", "password");
             restRequest.AddParameter("username", sUserName);
             restRequest.AddParameter("password", sPassword);
             try {
                 var response = restClient.Execute(restRequest);
                 if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.BadRequest){
                     dynamic objError = new ExpandoObject();
                     objError = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content);
                     access_token = "";
                     var error = objError.invalid_grant;
                     var error_description = objError.error_description;
                     MessageBox.Show(error + " - " + error_description, "Advertencia", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                 }
                 if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Accepted || response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK){
                     dynamic objRpta = new ExpandoObject();
                     objRpta = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content);
                     access_token = objRpta.access_token;
                     String token_type = objRpta.token_type;
                     int expires_in = objRpta.expires_in;
                 }
             }
             catch(IOException e){
                 MessageBox.Show(e.ToString(), "Advertencia", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
             }
             return access_token;
        }
```